# OpenAI GPT-3 API error: Why do I get an error when I try to implement an OpenAI API in my JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript, html, openai-api, gpt-3

I am trying to create a simple website using HTML and JavaScript using an OpenAI API where the user inputs a query and the model generates a response. Whenever I type something in the textbox and click a button to generate something, it will always show an error. Is this a problem with CORS restrictions, or is it a problem with my code?

Here is my JavaScript code:

```
function generateOutput() {
    var userInput = document.getElementById("input").value;

    fetch("https://api.openai.com/v1/engines/davinci-codex/completions", {
        method:"POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            Authorization: "Bearer 'MY_API'"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            prompt: userInput,
            max_tokens:50,
            model: "text-davinci-003"
        }),
    })
        .then(response => {
            if (response.ok) {
                return response.json();
            }else{
                throw new Error("Error occurred while communicating with the API.")
            }
        })
        .then(data => {
            const output = data.choices[0].text.trim();
            document.getElementById("output").textContent = output;
        })  
        .catch(error => {
            document.getElementById("errorMessage").textContent = "Error occurred while communicating with the API: " + error.message;
        });
}
```

In this code, a user can type something, and then generate a response by clicking a button. If there is an error, it will display the text "Error occurred while communicating with the API." I tried it without the error function, and it just displayed nothing while generating my request.

Comment: Put `console.log(response)` in the `else` block so you see the reason for the error.

Answer (score 0):

#### Problem

All [Engines API](https://platform.openai.com/docs/deprecations/2022-06-03-legacy-endpoints) endpoints are deprecated.

[image: Screenshot]

#### Solution

Use the [Completions API](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/gpt/completions-api) endpoint.

Change the URL from this...

```
https://api.openai.com/v1/engines/davinci-codex/completions
```

...to this.

```
https://api.openai.com/v1/completions
```

You probably used ChatGPT to write this code. The problem is that even the newest OpenAI models (i.e., GPT-3.5 and GPT-4) are trained with data up to June/September 2021, when Engines API endpoints were still in use. ChatGPT doesn't know that as of June 2023, it should suggest you use the [Completions API](https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/completions) endpoint instead of the Engines API endpoint.

#### Working example

Try this:

```
function generateOutput() {
  var userInput = document.getElementById("input").value;

  fetch("https://api.openai.com/v1/completions", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: "Bearer 'MY_API'"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        prompt: userInput,
        max_tokens: 50,
        model: "text-davinci-003"
      }),
    })
    .then(response => {
      if (response.ok) {
        return response.json();
      } else {
        throw new Error("Error occurred while communicating with the API.")
      }
    })
    .then(data => {
      const output = data.choices[0].text.trim();
      document.getElementById("output").textContent = output;
    })
    .catch(error => {
      document.getElementById("errorMessage").textContent = "Error occurred while communicating with the API: " + error.message;
    });
}
```