# OpenAI ChatGPT (GPT-3.5) API error in WordPress PHP code: "Invalid URL (POST /v4/engines/davinci-codex/completions)"

Tags: php, openai-api, chatgpt-api

I've asked ChatGPT to generate a code to be incorporated in WordPress' function.php to generate tags automatically for all my newly created or updated post.

Here is the code:

```
function add_tags_with_gpt($post_ID) {
    // Vérifier si le contenu de l'article a réellement changé
    $post = get_post($post_ID);
    $old_content = get_post_meta($post_ID, '_old_content', true);
    $new_content = $post->post_content;
    if ($old_content === $new_content) {
        return; // Le contenu n'a pas changé, donc on ne fait rien
    }
    update_post_meta($post_ID, '_old_content', $new_content);

    // Utiliser l'API OpenAI pour générer des tags
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.openai.com/v4/engines/davinci-codex/completions');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode(array(
        'prompt' => 'Generate tags for a blog post with the following content: '.$new_content,
        'max_tokens' => 60
    )));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Authorization: Bearer your_openai_api_key', // Remplacez 'your_openai_api_key' par votre véritable clé API
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    ));
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    if (!$response) {
        // Enregistrer l'erreur dans le fichier de log de débogage de WordPress
        error_log('Erreur lors de la génération de tags: ' . curl_error($ch));
        return;
    }
    curl_close($ch);

    // Enregistrer la réponse de l'API dans le fichier de log de débogage de WordPress
    error_log('Réponse de l\'API OpenAI : ' . $response);

    $response_data = json_decode($response, true);
    if(!isset($response_data['choices'][0]['text'])) {
        error_log('Erreur: La réponse de l\'API ne contient pas de tags');
        return;
    }
    $tags = explode(',', $response_data['choices'][0]['text']);
    $tags = array_slice($tags, 0, 8);

    // Valider et nettoyer les tags
    $tags = array_map('sanitize_text_field', $tags);
    $tags = array_map('wp_strip_all_tags', $tags);
    $tags = array_filter($tags, function($tag) {
        return strlen($tag) > 2 && strlen($tag) <= 20; // Exclure les tags de moins de 3 caractères et de plus de 20 caractères
    });

    // Ajouter les tags à l'article
    wp_set_post_tags($post_ID, $tags, true);
}
add_action('save_post', 'add_tags_with_gpt');
```

The problem is that the code doesn't work and returns this error message in debug.log

```
[23-Jul-2023 15:16:27 UTC] Réponse de l'API OpenAI : {
  "error": {
    "message": "Invalid URL (POST /v4/engines/davinci-codex/completions)",
    "type": "invalid_request_error",
    "param": null,
    "code": null
  }
}

[23-Jul-2023 15:16:27 UTC] Erreur: La réponse de l'API ne contient pas de tags
[23-Jul-2023 15:16:34 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  str_replace(): Passing null to parameter #3 ($subject) of type array|string is deprecated in /home/***/webapps/***/wp-includes/formatting.php on line 4303
```

Any idea what the issue is and how to fix it? The problem doesn't come from the API key that I copy/pasted from my OpenAI account into the code.

Many thanks,

Comment: Well, ChatGPT is not yet stable to deliver code well. If you still have the session opened, paste in the errors, and then continue to follow all its instructions. Mind thought that this advice as well as the question will be deleted on Stack Overflow as it is off-topic/banned. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76530321/1427878 says that _"All Engines API endpoints are deprecated."_ (That is referring to v1, but I would assume it applies to v4 as well?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All [Engines API](https://platform.openai.com/docs/deprecations/2022-06-03-legacy-endpoints) endpoints are deprecated.

[image: Screenshot]

Use the [Chat Completions API](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/gpt/chat-completions-api) endpoint.

Change the URL from this...

```
https://api.openai.com/v4/engines/davinci-codex/completions
```

...to this.

```
https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions
```

There are 4 required parameters for the [Chat Completions API](https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/chat):

- `model`
- `messages`

  - `role`
  - `content`

See my [past answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75613704/10347145) for a working example in PHP using the `gpt-3.5-turbo` model.